# Exception in JDeveloper

Tags: jdeveloper

I am making a soa application using JDeveloper(Studio Edition Version 11.1.1.5.0) with jdk 1.7 installed in my system and my RAM is 2GB. The problem is that even though my program logic is perfectly fine still at times i get an error, when i try to build it or deploy it in Weblogic Server. However the same program gets compiled after repeated trials of deployment and works perfectly fine.
The error in scac.log is as follows:

```
   Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
   Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Please help me fix this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

2gb of RAM is not enough. For soa development you need at least 4gb better 8gb of RAM. 
I'm not sure jdev 11.1.1.5.0 can run on jdk 1.7.0 as this combination is not verified.